# Cannot turn on developer mode on TCL 20 Pro after factory reset

Tags: settings, factory-reset, developer-options

I have an issue with a TCL 20 Pro not allowing me to activate the Developer mode. I've tried to use the normal method of going to 'About Phone and tapping the build button x7' but it does not work.

I have a second TCL 20 Pro with which this method does work with no problems. The only difference that I can see is the one that has the issue has been factory reset, but when I confirm the firmware they are using, they have the same band and the same firmware version.

I cannot re-flash the firmware from the bootloader as the stock firmware file is a .tctbin file which is not recognised by the bootloader and I cannot seem to find the usual .zip file used for flashing.

My questions are:

- Is there a workaround, ie: using the fastboot mode to enable dev mode and or the serial port?
- Also, is the .tctbin the correct file type for flashing the TCL 20 Pro from a TS card?

Comment: Please describe in detail what "does not work" means. What error do you see when you try to activate developer mode?